# How can I test React custom hook with RTL which uses react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-query, react-hooks-testing-library

I've a custom React hook which uses react-query useQuery() in it-self:

```
const useFetchSomething = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery('key', ....);
  return .......
}
```

I had to create a custom hook then use the `useQuery()` hook inside it, because it has some features and gets data from react-query!

I tried to test this hook with `react-hooks-testing-library`:

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetchSomething());
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one]
```

for this, how can I wrap this part: `renderHook(() => useFetchSomething())` with Provider?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[renderHook](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook) accepts `options`, and one of them is the [wrapper](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#wrapper) component, where you can specify a react component to wrap the test component in when rendering. This is a good place to put providers.

```
const createWrapper = () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()
  return ({ children }) => (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetchSomething(), {
  wrapper: createWrapper()
});
```

I have an [in-depth guide to testing react query](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/testing-react-query) in my blog.

Comment: Can you please check  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787517/getting-error-no-queryclient-set-use-queryclientprovider-using-react-testing